# How to iterate over <td> tags with condition  using jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, iteration, jsoup

I am able get all text with in  tags but I want to access only specific td tags.
Eg.I want to get data of second cell text whose first cell html contains attribute
a name="manufacturer"
or Content.I am using Jsoup.

```
      <tabel>
     <tr>
      <td><a name="Manufacturer"></a>manufacturer</td>
      <td>happiness</td>
    </tr>
      <td>manuf</td>
      <td>hap</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>tents</td>
     <td>acd</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><a name="Content"></a>Contents</td>
     <td>abcd</td>
    </tr> 
  </tabel>
```

I am using the code ..

```
  doc.select("a[name=Manufacturer]");
```

..but its giving me the reference of cell one ,I need to go to cell two get cell two text

Answer (score 0):

You need to use selector like `[attr=value]: elements with attribute value, e.g. [width=500]`.

Take a look at official documentation [Selector Syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: I tried but it gives me the text of cell one which has the attribute but i need to go to next cell of the same row and its not going there

Comment: you can use `getElementsByAttribute(String key)` and than iterate it

Comment: i Tried that also and its give me object of cell 1 which has the attribute ,i need to go to cell two after getting reference of cell one

Comment: what abt `nextElementSibling`

Comment: I am using the code Elements asf=doc.select("a[name=Administration]");
for(Element puy:asf)
S.o.p("Next:"+puy.nextElementSibling());//gives me null